# Why is it that histogram equalization actually distributs all intensity values uniformly over the whole range?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

This [article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/01/histogram-equalization/#wait_approval) shows the  following transformation function for histogram equalization

$$s = T(r) = (L-1) \int_0^r Pr(w) \,dw$$

Where $L$ is the maximum value a pixel can achieve. $Pr(r)$ is probability density function (pdf) of the image before equalization and $Ps(s)$ is pdf of the image after performing equalization.

It then states that the relation between $Pr(r)$ and $Ps(s)$ is

$$Ps(s) = Pr(r) \bigg|\frac{ds}{dr} \bigg|$$

where

$$\frac{ds}{dr} = \frac{d}{dr}T(r)$$

I can't understand how the pdf of $s$ is the pdf of $r$ times the absolute value of the derivative of $T(r)$ with respect to $r$.

Can you help me understand why this relation holds?